# Including a RelatedList of tasks in a broadcast email via Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, related-list

So I'm just trying to see if this is possible. I've been tasked with trying to find a way to include a related list in a broadcast email template.

Some background, we use Tasks for student forms and track whether they're completed or not. So what is wanted is for me to include complete and incomplete Tasks in a broadcast email that will be sent out to students as a reminder to complete the rest of their forms.

I was thinking that I could use a visualforce relatedlist to recreate the related list on the contact record and then include it in broadcast emails.

The problem is that I have no idea of where to start or how to estimate my hours and level of effort for the project because I don't know if it's possible at all.

So I'm asking if anyone has done this, and is it possible? Is a VF RelatedList the way to go with this?

How do I include a relatedlist in broadcast emails if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to pass the child relationship into the standard `apex:relatedList` component, this would be a trivial task to complete within a day. Even if that doesn't work, you would be able create a `VisualForce Component` (may also need a controller) to mimic that functionality and then include that in your `VisualForce Email Template`.